# Referencing schema names for tables in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, data-access

How do you explicitally tell EF that a table lies in a specific schema?

For example, the AdventureWorks database defines the Production.Product table. When using the `OnModelCreating` method, I use the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    EntityTypeConfiguration<Product> config = modelBuilder.Entity<Product>();

    config.HasKey(p => p.ProductID);
    config.Property(p => p.Price).HasColumnName("ListPrice");
    config.ToTable("Product");
}
```

However, when it is run, it says it `Invalid object name: dbo.Product`.

I have tried:

```
config.ToTable("Production.Product");
//and
config.HasEntityName("Production");
```

but both fail as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ToTable` has overloaded version which accepts two parameters: table name and schema name so correct version is:

```
config.ToTable("Product", "Production");
```

Answer (score 0):

The table schema can also be specified using data annotations using the optional parameter 'Schema' on the 'Table' attribute.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("Product", Schema="Production")]
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```